# Are embedded styles bad practice?

Tags: symfony

I have many templates in my project that vary slightly from one another. I am finding it a hassle to create new 'sections' in my css file to accomodate this.

Is putting something like this in my template frowned upon?

```
{% block stylesheets %}
{{ parent() }}
<style>

  #chart {
    height: 350px;
  }
  .aside h4 {
    margin: 0;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
  }

</style>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %]
...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whether it's frowned upon or not, always keep yourself [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)! If there's a possibility of you using lines of code elsewhere, move it out into a referable block. CSS should be easy to keep dry.

Comment: Here I'm defining the height of charts on different dashboard-like pages, so things will always change. I do have a global that I use for reusable styles.

Comment: Even for that you could have a reusable class of `height350px` rather than setting the height on that single block. Granted you'd have extra markup.

Answer (score 2):

No embedded style sheets are not bad. it depends on case to case basis. According to you, if u can write css file from scratch, you should do this or rely upon template's css, it is best to use embedded(if the project is small).

You can write common css for some element like headings, input fields, buttons if you find it time taking for writing embedded style css.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, I use this technique:

1) each template generates specific class in the body or some enveloping DIV

```
 <body class="myTemplate">...

 <body class="otherTemplate">...
```

2) I specify general style, like

```
h1 { color: red; }
```

3) then I specify special styles for specific templates, using context selectors:

```
.myTemplate h1 { color: green; }
.otherTemplate h1 { color: blue; }
```

This way I avoid dynamic stylesheets, because that is usually a bad idea to introduce these to the project. It is a source of many errors and duynamic code tends to grow beyond controll.

Comment: This is how I was doing it, but then it became very complicated. I had one massive style sheet with `/** Template**/` to find where those template-specific rules were. Now, I just have the two or three page-specific rules in the template, and it seems much more sensible. What do you think?

Comment: I can imagine a situation when this could make sense, but I didn't encounter it yet. On the other hand, I would probably prefer page specific stylesheets linked to the page, because they are easier to debug and you can use caching for better performance.